# PHP Photo/File Upload Issues

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

Been looking around as i'm having a few issues with PHP file upload! I'm trying to upload a photo or three to a database (admin_images) if the user wants to or show the photo that's already stored in the db. I'm having some issues, below is my code I currently have, any advice is welcome.

```
 require_once 'connect/config.php'; 
 require_once 'connect/opendb.php';
 require_once 'connect/magic.quotes.php';

 $home_query = "SELECT * FROM admin"; 
$home_rt = mysql_query($home_query); 
$home_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($home_rt);

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {      $HomeTitle = check_input($_POST['HomeTitle']);      $HomeBio = check_input($_POST['HomeBio']);

    $home_query = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET HomeTitle = '".$HomeTitle."', HomeBio = '".$HomeBio."' WHERE ID = 1");  


            foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $f => $name)    {
                $name = strtolower($name);
                $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");      $temp = explode(".", $name);        $extension = end($temp);
                if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))      {           if($_FILES['file']['size'][$f] < 2000000)           {
                $uniqid = uniqid();

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], "upload/" . $uniqid  . "." . $extension);

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_images (id, HomeImage1, HomeImage2, HomeImage3) VALUES (".$last_id.", '".$uniqid .".".$extension."')");
                        }           else            {
                        }       }       else        {
                }   }   header("Location: home1.php");

}  require_once 'connect/closedb.php'; ?
```

In the PHP further down the page I have included:

```
input type="file" name="files[]" multiple
```

Apologies if I'm being unclear. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is old-fashioned, using now deprecated functions. I'd be tempted to start again with a more up-to-date tutorial on the subject or a (free and) off-the-shelf solution that makes proper use of PDO (or mysqli_) and, crucially, prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

By using `$_FILES['file']` you are telling the PHP to get file from input type with name "file" -the input you show has a different name (actually its an array).

it is best to dump the $_FILES array to view the actual data in it.
`var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). it gives detail process. match the format and check for any bug.